# Events tracked via Measurement protocol are not being sent to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I have a GA4 property linked to BigQuery and my application is sending some custom events. Some of the events are sent by the standard JS library, and some of the events are being sent by the back-end, via the Measurement Protocol API.

All events are visible in the Realtime report in the GA dashboard. However, when I look at the data that is sent to BigQuery, only the events sent via the front-end are there. Events sent via the Measurement Protocol API are not present in BigQuery.

I did not create any custom event or custom dimensions in the GA dashboard, as I understand this is not a requirement for the data that is sent to BigQuery.

Are the events tracked by the Measurement Protocol API expected to be seen in BigQuery? Any other action needed?

Comment: Have you validated that the events sent by Measurement protocol are visible in GA$ UI?

Comment: @Tushar Yes, I see them in the Real time report.

Comment: ok and how much time have you waited to check in BQ? For eg: To see today's data, you need to query BQ tomorrow (at least give 24hrs)

Comment: @Tushar I have waited few days already. I triggered some events on Friday and checked again today (there was also some events before that and I still don't see them. But I see all the events that were sent by the front-end

Comment: can you add an example MP hit here that you have already sent?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for your help. As I looked into it, I realized I was sending the back-end events to another testing property! I pointed it to the same property and I'm already able to see the custom events in BigQuery. All good!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, events sent via the Measurement Protocol API are expected to be sent to BigQuery when the property is linked. No additional configuration required.

I was sending events to wrong property and that's why I wasn't seeing them!